# Dwg comparison through design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I would like to know if it is possible, and if yes, how can I achieve dwg comparison through the design automation? I there a way to create a comparison activity accepting 2 dwg in input, and post a boolean as output?

Comment: normally, Design Automation works only with the features that do not need to interact with UI. I am not sure if the core workflow of DWG Compare. Please bear with me checking with engineer team

Comment: We had some discussion with team. Although we could run the built-in commands [-COMPARE], but this command creates a new diff drawing （in-place drawing),  so switching document is main issue to run a command on new in-place `diff drawing. We are checking further with engineer team if there is any possibility we can call the core logic of COMPARE command, getting the comparison result, instead of executing the command. Will keep you updated

Comment: I'll not use the built-in commands but a specific one uploaded with an app package. But I wonder how to specify an activity and an apppackage that'll take 2 dwg in input and post a boolean (as a json maybe?) in output.

Comment: Sorry, I am still discussing with engineer team. I got some info, but not get got a final comment that I can share with you. Will keep you updated.

Comment: finally, we got the working script now. my colleague Madhukar has tested. He will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an activity accepting two drawings.
Following activity JSON uses an in-built compare and output the result diff drawing.

**Sample Activity Json**

```
{
    "HostApplication": "",
    "RequiredEngineVersion": "23.0",
    "Parameters": {
        "InputParameters": [
            {
                "Name": "HostDwg",
                "LocalFileName": "$(HostDwg)"
            },
            {
                "Name": "ToCompareWith",
                "LocalFileName": "ToCompareWith.dwg"
            }
        ],
        "OutputParameters": [
            {
                "Name": "Result",
                "LocalFileName": "output.dwg"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Instruction": {
        "CommandLineParameters": null,
        "Script": "COMPAREINPLACE\nON\n-COMPARE\n\nToCompareWith.dwg\n_SAVEAS\n\noutput.dwg\n"
    },
    "Id": "FPDCompare"
}
```

**Workitem Json**

```
{
    "Arguments": {
        "InputArguments": [
            {
                "Resource": "https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Kitchens1.dwg",
                "Name": "HostDwg"
            },
            {
                "Resource": "https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Kitchens2.dwg",
                "Name": "ToCompareWith"
            }
        ],
        "OutputArguments": [
            {
                "Name": "Result",
                "HttpVerb": "POST"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ActivityId": "FPDCompare"
}
```

> If you are using your own custom compare logic, you can output the
>   results to txt file or json file.

**Activity Json**

```
{
    "HostApplication": "",
    "RequiredEngineVersion": "23.0",
    "Parameters": {
        "InputParameters": [
            {
                "Name": "HostDwg",
                "LocalFileName": "$(HostDwg)"
            },
            {
                "Name": "ToCompareWith",
                "LocalFileName": "ToCompareWith.dwg"
            }
        ],
        "OutputParameters": [
            {
                "Name": "Result",
                "LocalFileName": "output.txt"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Instruction": {
        "CommandLineParameters": null,
        "Script": "ISDWGSIMILAR\nToCompareWith.dwg\n"
    },
    "AppPackages":["Compare"],
    "Version": 1,
    "Id": "Compare"
}
```

**Workitem Json**

```
{
    "Arguments": {
        "InputArguments": [
            {
                "Resource":"https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Kitchens.dwg",
                "Name": "HostDwg"
            },
            {
                "Resource":"https://madhukar-fda.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Kitchens1.dwg",
                "Name": "ToCompareWith"
            }
        ],
        "OutputArguments": [
            {
                "Name": "Result",
                "HttpVerb": "POST"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ActivityId": "Compare"
}
```

Note: In the script argument - "ISDWGSIMILAR" is a custom command where you will process two drawings, the first one will be current and second one is the drawing to which you are willing compare [ToCompareWith]

**Custom NET Command**

```
    [CommandMethod("FDACOMMANDS", "ISDWGSIMILAR", CommandFlags.Transparent)]
    public static void CompareDrawing()
    {
        var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var db = doc.Database;
        var ed = doc.Editor;
        var promptResult = ed.GetString("Select Drawing To Compare With");
        if (promptResult.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
        var drawingToCompareWith = promptResult.StringResult;
        ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        using (OpenCloseTransaction o = new OpenCloseTransaction())
        {
           /*

           {

           Here your logic code to compare two drawings

           }

           */

            /*output.txt / json is pushed to your cloud storage as provided in workitem json*/
            using (var writer = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
            {
                if (b != null) /*b value is result of your compare*/
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("TRUE Drawings are same");
                }
                else writer.WriteLine("FALSE Drawings aren't same");
            }
        }
    }
```